# media queries max width 320px issue

Tags: html, css, width, media

I have a problem with media queries in a 320px width. 
I tried the next codes to set the query but browsers don't recognise it, so it doesn't work correctly:

1- @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {

2- @media (min-width:320 px) and (max-width:480 px)

3- @media (max-width: 320px){

None of them work for me. What am I doing wrong?

THANKS A LOT!

Comment: Other than the spaces before the `px` in the second code there is nothing wrong with your media queries [-working demo-](http://jsfiddle.net/h7f9k3d6/)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
@media only screen and (min-width:3.33%){
.yourClass{
    width : 20%;
  }
}
```

And its better that u use `%` instead of `px`

Comment: Sorry, 3.33% of what?